# Unable to connect to Teradata from excel using VBA code - Teradata Server can't be reached over the network

Tags: vba, excel, ado, teradata

I have been trying to connect to Teradata from Excel using vba code but I am getting the below mentioned error:
Teradata Server can't be reached over the network. I have been able to successfully connect from Teradata SQL assistant and I also successfully pinged the Teradata server(I am using Teradata express edition in my laptop which runs on VMware player). I also successfully connected to Teradata from Excel Data connection wizard and Microsoft query. I have also switched off the firewall and checked to see If I am able to connect but still no luck in connecting. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Please find below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim thisSql As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open "Driver=Teradata;DBCName=dsnname;Databasename=dbname;Uid=Userid;Pwd=****;"

thisSql = "sel * from customer_db.customer"

Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rec1.Open thisSql, conn

With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change the Connection object's Open method:

`conn.Open "DSN=dsnname;Databasename=dbname;Uid=Userid;Pwd=****;"`

Answer (score 2):

This connection script worked for me.

```
' Add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library in References
' When installing Teradata SQL Assistant, include the ODBC Driver for Teradata will install the TDOLEDB provider
' This example connects to Teradata, deletes the contents of MyTable & inserts row 7- 8 from the active spreadsheet

Function OpenConn() As Object
    Set OpenConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim myConnectionString As String
    myConnectionString = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=MyTeradataServerName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyTeradataUserID;Password=MyTeradataPass;Session Mode=ANSI;DefaultDatabase=GRP_BCE_FINANCE_IM;MaxResponseSize=65477;"
    OpenConn.Open myConnectionString
End Function

Sub CloseConn(conn As Object)
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub

Sub PushCCHier()
    Dim TeraObjCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim TeraObjRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim TeraObjRs2 As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim TeraCnxn As Object
    Set TeraCnxn = OpenConn()

    TeraObjCmd.ActiveConnection = TeraCnxn

    'Clear Previous Data
    TeraObjCmd.ActiveConnection = TeraCnxn
    TeraObjCmd.CommandText = "delete from MyTable"
    TeraObjCmd.Execute

    'Load New Data
    Set TeraObjRs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
    TeraObjRs2.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable where 1 = 2 ", TeraCnxn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    With TeraObjRs2
        For irow = 7 To 8 'loading results from rows in my spredsheet
            If Len(Trim(Range("B" & irow).Value)) <> 0 Then 'Avoid blank rows
                .AddNew
                .Fields(0) = Range("B" & irow).Value
            End If
        Next
        .UpdateBatch
        .Close
    End With

    ' clean up objects
    Set objCmd = Nothing
    Call CloseConn(TeraCnxn)
    MsgBox "Update Complete!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative connection string to connect to Teradata:

```
"Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=myPassword;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myUserid;Data Source=myDSN"
```