# How to insert excel rows into Teradata table

Tags: excel, vba, teradata, adodb

I have an excel sheet where in I wish to insert selected excel rows into Teradata table using vba. So far I have managed to retrieve data from Teradata using following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim thisSql As String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "PROVIDER=***;AUTHENTICATION=***;Driver=*****;DBCName=******;Uid=*****;Pwd=******;"

    thisSql = "sel * from Database.table1"

    Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rec1.Open thisSql, conn

    With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1"))
        .Name = "data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This brings all the data from the teradata table (5 columns) in to excel sheet starting at `A1:E10`.

**First Problem**: Every time I click the button, the table is inserted from position `A1`, which means any previous data is pushed to `F1:J10`. I want to replace/overwrite the data at `A-E` if button is clicked again and not add/duplicate it by pushing previous data to `F-J`.

**Second Problem**: Allow user to type in more rows in same sheet or sheet 2 in same workbook and have a button that takes that data and inserts into teradata table.

I am unable to find a fitting example for my requirements. I checked [How to insert data into Teradata Table from Excel (using VBA macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676981/how-to-insert-data-into-teradata-table-from-excel-using-vba-macro) but it did not help my problem.

Comment: **Problem 1** Add `.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells`

Comment: **Problem 2** Did [Unable to connect to Teradata from excel using VBA code - Teradata Server can't be reached over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379191/unable-to-connect-to-teradata-from-excel-using-vba-code-teradata-server-cant) not help? See answer by David. Posting a code that you tried may help.